# NavHost recomposes couple of times when it is not needed to

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

Hello dear programmers!

I faced an issue that I don't know how to deal with. And the issue is that I place NavHost inside Scaffold which require me to use paddings. Here are the actual code:

```
Scaffold(
    bottomBar = {
        BottomGamesBar(
            navController = navController,
            destinations = destinations.filter {
                it.key == HomeEntry::class.java ||
                        it.key == FavouriteFeatureEntry::class.java
            }
        )
    }
) { padding ->
    Box (
        //modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = padding.calculateBottomPadding())
    ) {
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = destinations.find<HomeEntry>().destination(),
        ) {
            with(destinations.find<HomeEntry>()) {
                screen(navController, destinations)
            }
            with(destinations.find<GameDetailsEntry>()) {
                screen(navController, destinations)
            }
            with(destinations.find<FavouriteFeatureEntry>()) {
                screen(navController, destinations)
            }
        }
        Settings(
            navController = navController,
            destinations = destinations,
            settingsViewModel = settingsViewModel
        )
    }
}
```

As you can see, I commented modifier with padding at the moment. Now let's look at what LayoutInspector says about recomposition when I navigating to different screen which doesn't need BottomNavigationBar and due to that have different paddings in scaffold body
[It shows that this way NavHost do not recomposes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzFF4.png)

So that means that only animations and all that underhoodstuff recomposes and that's exactly what I need. But this is wrong! Because some part of ui that is below NavBar is not visible, which is actually obvious, I didn't add paddings. So let's add them.
[Alright here they are.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMKRm.png)

Oopsie, now NavHost recomposes like 8 times. And I don't want it like that. So how to do it properly? The thing is that I need some screens with NavBar and some without. But if I am using Scaffold I need to use paddings so that screen will fit normally and every time I navigate to screen which don't have BottomNavBar.

Comment: You can not fix it because it is "intended behaviour" said by compose tema.

Comment: @ChiragThummar well then it is a bad thing to me.. When I remove padding navigation do not lag. But if I add them I clearly can see some lags there. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: You can check i have raised the issue : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/302212882